# Oracle 10g for Windows does not start up on system boot

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We have an Oracle 10g Enterprise Edition installation (10.2.0.1.0) on a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine. It was initially created with Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1 but has now been migrated to Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V.

The services start on system boot, but the instance does not start up. This problem was actually occurring on Virtual Server after a migration from one server to another, but I managed to fix it then with:

```
oradim -edit -sid ORCL -startmode auto
```

However, this now has no effect.

oradim.log (in %OracleHome%\database\oradim.log) says:

```
Thu Jun 10 14:14:48 2010
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_3\bin\oradim.exe -startup -sid orcl -usrpwd * -log oradim.log -nocheck 0
Thu Jun 10 14:14:48 2010
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

sqlnet.log in the same folder has:

```
Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle)(ARGV0=oracleorcl)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))'))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_3\bin\oradim.exe)(HOST=ORACLE-VM)(USER=SYSTEM))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
        Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 10-JUN-2010 14:14:48
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12560
    TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 530
    TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
    nt secondary err code: 2
    nt OS err code: 0
```

The `ORA_ORCL_AUTOSTART` registry value is set to `TRUE`, so it should be auto-starting - and you can see that it's trying to. The problem also occurs when stopping and restarting the *OracleServiceORCL* service.

I've enabled SQL*Net tracing which shows:

```
[10-JUN-2010 15:09:33.919] snlpcss: entry
[10-JUN-2010 15:09:34.419] snlpcss: Unable to spawn Oracle oracle     (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq))) orcl, error 2.
[10-JUN-2010 15:09:34.419] snlpcall: exit
```

On a hunch that error 2 is Windows error 2 (file not found) I tried restarting the service with Process Monitor watching oradim.exe, but this appears to delay things just enough that it always works.

Right now I have a horrible hack where I've created a Scheduled Task to run `oradim -startup -sid ORCL` when the Administrator account logs on, and set the VM to auto-logon. I'd still like to work out why it's not working.

Comment: So, to be clear: it's the autostart that fails, but you can bring up the instance manually? Or not?

Comment: @DCookie: autostart fails but bringing up the instance with oradim or by running 'startup' from sqlplus works. It's only auto-starting that's a problem.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not running 10.2.0.4?

Comment: You should really look at the alert log to determine why it's not starting. It's usually in C:\Oracle\product\10.2.0\admin\bdump\alert.log (location can vary). The sqlnet log and tracing are red herrings - the database starts independently of the network stack.

Comment: If the Windows machinename/servername changed check if listener.ora contains a reference to the old name and update it. Usually listed in a `(HOST=XXXX)` part of a listener configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth, for a test, adding a dependency to the service.  I'm wondering whether it's trying to start too early.  I've seen a similar problem in the past, and cannot remember what we did to fix it, but we now use the Oracle agent / Grid Control to bring the services up (i.e.: Agent => Auto start, Oracle => Manual, Etc).

Answer (score 0):

run `tnsping .`
go to directory with parameters file `sqlnet.ora`
edit files `tnsnames.ora` & `listener.ora`
correct `(HOST = your_db_host_name)` to value returned by `hostname` command
run `services.msc`
restart oracle listener service named `OracleOra....Listener` & instance service named `OracleService....`